# Alternative to UNION with indexing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index, view, union

I'm on SQL Server 2012 and I have tables for different companies each one with its own customers:

```
CompanyA_Customers:

ID | Name
---------
11 | Foo
12 | Bar

CompanyB_Customers:

ID | Name
---------
11 | Baz
12 | Qux
```

And I need a single table to query them, so I did this:

```
CREATE VIEW Customers AS
    SELECT 'A' AS Company, ID, Name FROM CompanyA_Customers
UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' AS Company, ID, Name FROM CompanyB_Customers
```

but I suffer poor performance since as far as I know on a `UNION` view I can't define any index.

Are there any alternatives to have better performance?

Comment: You can't use a `UNION` in a `VIEW` definition. Can you post the execution plan of your query? I think your schema design will cause you pain as you add new customers.

Comment: @James Anderson, why can't you use a union in a view? Is this a limitation in sql-server?

Comment: @JamesAnderson did you mean indexed view? As far as I know a view can be defined for any, arbitrary query.

Comment: @ypercube yes I was talking about indexed views and didn't make that clear. Thanks

Comment: In your 'question' example, your tables are defined with only 2 columns (ID, Name).  Is that really the entire definition of those tables or was that example shortened because those are the only columns needed by the view.  "If' there are numerous extra columns on the source tables, then creating 'covering' indexes on ID and Name should make the query faster due to less pages being scanned.  You didn't say which edition of Sql Server you're using, but data compression, if possible, could also improve the query.  Posting the plan xml might give us more clues.

Comment: @ScottHodgin the columns are just an example, in the real case scenario there are more than 50 columns I need on the view and at least 5 indexed. SQL Server is 2012. I'll check for the plan and update my answer.

Comment: @GiovanniLovato, do the queries that select from this view include  `WHERE` or `JOIN`clauses?   I don't see how indexes on the view will improve performance based in the information in your question.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, there are many restrictions for indexed views, such as no `UNION` or `OUTER` joins,.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx..

Comment: @DanGuzman I know. The very first comment by James was suggesting that there are restrictions in plain (indexed or not) views.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, sorry, I read the comments as in the context of the indexed view question.

Comment: Don't have separate tables.  One table with customer ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO (and as [Paparazzi](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/14476/paparazzi) has pointed out on comments) the easiest way to accomplish it and get better performance is using a single table by adding a CompanyID field.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    CompanyID   <some_type> REFERENCES Companies (CompanyID),
    CustomerID  <some_type> REFERENCES Customers (CustomerID),
    Name        text,
    PRIMARY KEY (CompanyID, CustomerID)
);
```

If you cannot modify your actual table schema, you could use two materialized views, one for each company, and add a clustered index on (company_id, id) or (id, company_id) depending on your queries.

I've set up a fiddle **[here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4fe2c4db993d9dc559d09699ab9e1643)**

```
select company_id, id, name
from (
      select company_id, id, name from dbo.vcustA
      union all
      select company_id, id, name from dbo.vcustB
     ) x
where id = 2;
```

Execution plan for two materialized views using UNION:

[image]

But in fact, this is worst than create a new table with all records of both tables. Instead of use two materialized views, I'd suggest to create a new table and, using triggers, add/update/delete all records from customersA and customersB. Or set up a daily job that synchronize this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [partitioned table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730.aspx) to horizontally partition you data.

Partitioned tables is an Enterprise edition feature, if you are on a lesser edition you could alternatively create a partitioned view, see this link for an example https://auntkathisql.com/2015/08/26/what-is-a-partitioned-view/

If you are using SQL Server 2016, you could also put all the data in one table and use [Row-Level Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx) to expose the correct data to the relevant customers.

Comment: Doesn't he essentially have a partitioned view now? Not sure how any sort of partitioning will help unless there's a where clause that filters on the partitioning key.